# Strange behaviour from system call creat

Tags: c++, c, unix, system-calls

I am creating a file as follows

```
 int fd  = creat(file_path.c_str() ,S_IRWXU|S_IRWXG|S_IRWXO);
```

Though i am providing all permissions to all three entities, it creates the files with the below permission.

```
-rwxr-xr-x
```

The directory i am creating this in has permissions set as

```
drwxrwxrwx
```

Umask

```
0022
```

Can you guys please suggest what could be wrong?

Edit : I can chmod the file to give it the permissions i plan to. I am curious why the above is failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Permissions in the umask are turned off from the mode argument to `open` and `mkdir` (and `creat` and friends, similarly). For example, if the `mode` argument is specified as:

`S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP | S_IROTH | S_IWOTH` (0666) when creating a file with the typical umask of 0022, the result will be

`S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH` (0644)

So, you are correctly seeing write access not being given to the directory you're creating.

Answer (score 4):

You said it yourself, you have a umask of 022, so the write permission is omitted; From the creat man page:

> The effective permissions are modified by the process's umask in the usual way: The permissions of the created file are (mode & ~umask).

Answer (score 3):

You are likely running under a umask restriction

```
man umask
```

should get you onto the right track

Answer (score 3):

The umask is combined with the file permissions you specify in the `creat` call in this way `file_perms & ~umask` to arrive at the permission bits that are actually set for the file. The umask basically specifies which bits should not be set even if you request they be set.

The `chmod` call ignores the umask. And your directory permissions are irrelevant here (well, not totally irrelevant, it would fail completely if you didn't have write permission to the directory you're creating the file in).

Comment: @Ricko M: You're welcome. A word of advice... you should wait for awhile before accepting an answer. The first person to give a halfway decent answer is not always the person who gives the best answer. I'm not saying mine is better. That's for you to judge. But if you accept within 5 minutes you might be missing out on a better answer.